# How can I redirect the user to my view?

Tags: views, uri

I made a view ("exampleview") that needs an argument: myarg. I can load my page at "exampleview/myarg" and at "exampleview".

When I call `drupal_goto(exampleview/myarg)`, the destination is only "exampleview".

I get the same result with `$arr = array('exampleview','myarg');`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you not just missing the '' around the path? `drupal_goto('exampleview/myarg');`

Comment: no, not so simple

Comment: try use this `url()` function. If it is creating right output then `drupal_goto()` should work.

Comment: I just tested drupal_goto('view/path/argument') with D7 views 3, which display with "subfolder" arguments and it worked fine, another issue perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This is from [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

> Usually the redirected URL is constructed from this function's input parameters. However you may override that behavior by setting a destination in either the $_REQUEST-array (i.e. by using the query string of an URI) This is used to direct the user back to the proper page after completing a form. For example, after editing a post on the 'admin/content'-page or after having logged on using the 'user login'-block in a sidebar. The function drupal_get_destination() can be used to help set the destination URL.

It seems like your destination parameter is set so you have to clear destination parameter or use [header function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)